# Array Issue not getting expected result

Tags: c#

I have a code that should check a list of elements in an array and the resulting list should give me eliminating the repeating values.
Here is my code

```
List <int> ProductListFinalized = new List<int>(ProductIdList);

for(int i = 0 ; i < ProductIdList.Count(); i++) 
{   
    int ProductId = ProductIdList[i];
    Res= !(ProductListFinalized.Contains(ProductId));
    if(!(ProductListFinalized.Contains(ProductId)))
    {
        ProductListFinalized.Add(ProductId); 
    }   
}

ProductIdListForCycleCount = ProductListFinalized.ToArray();
```

I am still finding the repeating values in the resulting Array. Whats is wrong with my code?

Comment: `new List<int>(ProductIdList);`, you certainly don't want that

Comment: you can use Distinct : `ProductListFinalized.Select(x => x.ProductId).Distinct();`

Comment: @VincentElbertBudiman Or use a `HashSet<int>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `List<int> ProductListFinalized = new List<int>(ProductIdList);` created a new list with the same values that `ProductIdList`, so always they'll be contain of list.

You have to create an empty list:

```
List<int> ProductListFinalized = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, You are already entering "all entities" by running this line:

```
List <int> ProductListFinalized = new List<int>(ProductIdList);
```

As List will get larger based on needs, You can simply do:

```
var ProductListFinalized = new List<int>(); //Do not enter parameter here
```

---

Also to simplify the running process, You can avoid the C# usage of `for`, and use a LINQ query `Distinct()` for the expected results.

```
var ProductListFinalized = ProductIdList.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from the docs, [`List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the `List<T>` class that contains elements copied from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to accommodate the number of elements copied.

But, you don't want a `List<T>` here, you want a [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

> If collection contains duplicates, the set will contain one of each unique element. No exception will be thrown. Therefore, the size of the resulting set is not identical to the size of collection.

So, your entire code could be reduced to just this:

```
var productListFinalized = new HashSet<int>(ProductIdList);
```